# Java casting negative Integer to Double gives wrong result

Tags: java, types, integer, double, overflow

I'm trying to cast an `Integer` to `Double` but Java is giving me wrong results, i believe due to overflow.

```
Integer ii = -123456789;
Double dd = ii.DoubleValue();
System.out.println(dd);
```

I am expecting to receive -123456789.0, but instead i am getting -1.23456789E8.

Is there a way to get rid of the decimals to gain a little range in the integer part? Or another data type with bigger range?

PS. Im converting code from another language that allows this with the same number of variable bytes.

Comment: Define _wrong_. What is the difference between those _numbers_?

Comment: Well, visually. I expect the decimal point to be printed in the correct position. I cant print it like this in invoices.

Comment: You're actually casting to `float`, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Are these numbers [representing currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)?

Comment: I hope you aren't using floating types to store currency amounts...

Comment: I started learning not long ago. Is there a specific way to do it? (specific like everything else in this language)

Comment: I can't replicated your reported behavior. What version of Java are you running?

Comment: Elliott, i have no idea what version of Java i am using. But i followed Soltirios' link and that gave me a solution... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `double` try with `BigDecimal`

```
Integer ii = -123456789;
BigDecimal dd = new BigDecimal(ii);
System.out.println(dd);
```